# Eigenvalues of $ \begin{pmatrix} (1+\beta) \boldsymbol{I}_d - \alpha \Lambda & -\beta I_d \\ I_d & 0_d \end{pmatrix} $

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3595v7.pdf) appendix A, the author tries to compute the eigenvalues of 
$ \begin{pmatrix} (1+\beta) \boldsymbol{I}_d - \alpha \Lambda & -\beta \boldsymbol{I}_d \\ \boldsymbol{I}_d & \boldsymbol{0}_d \end{pmatrix} $
where $\boldsymbol{I}_d, \boldsymbol{0}_d \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ are the identity matrix and zero matrix. $\boldsymbol{\Lambda} = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_d)$ is a diagonal matrix. The author decomposes the matrix to 
\begin{equation}
    T_i = \begin{bmatrix} (1+\beta) - \alpha \lambda_i & -\beta \\
1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}, \quad i =1,2,\ldots, d
\end{equation} and computes the eigenvalues of $T_i$.

How to deduce it?

Answer (score 1):

$\Lambda$ is diagonal. Therefore your matrix is similar (via conjugation of a permutation matrix) to $T_1\oplus T_2\oplus\cdots\oplus T_d$. Hence its eigenvalues are precisely the eigenvalues of $T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_d$. (Actually the same conclusion holds even if $\Lambda$ is not a diagonal matrix, but this is unimportant here. See the thread [Eigenvalues of block matrix related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727265/eigenvalues-of-block-matrix-related) if you are interested.)